# In my SSIS package, I need to give the FTP connection details from a stored procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, ssis, ftp, server

In my SSIS package, I need to give the FTP connection details like (server , port username ,password in Ftp connection manager dialog box ) from a stored procedure? Even if i use variables , i need the value for those variables from stored procedure(s). Please help me . Thanks